# How to install Eclipse plugins on Aptana Studio 3+

Tags: eclipse, plugins, installation, aptana

I've got to install this Eclipse plugin http://sourceforge.jp/downloads/users/0/774/pdt_tools.indentGuide_1.2.1.zip
which is zip-archive containing jar-files.

Can somebody tell me how to install it to the Aptana Studio 3+

Thanks guys!

PS: Maybe i'm wrong and this zip aint an Eclipse plugin at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Help > Install New Software > Add... > Archive...

Haven't tried this with a local file before, let us know how if it works.

Comment: I starting looking for this answer, and actually was even installing the same plugin! Worked beautifully.

Comment: I was also trying to install this plugin. Thank you so much for this answer. For those of you who are still slightly confused, in the Install New Software dialog, there's an address bar near the top where you normally enter the url of a repository, beside that is an Add... button; that's what Sarah's talking about here.